# Python 3.4.3. why wont my program save my dictionary key after false input?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, input, key

Here's my code:

```
def add_goose_group():
    goose_group_name = input('Insert the name of the raft ')
    goose_group_name = str(goose_group_name)
    if goose_group_name.isdigit() == False and (' ' in goose_group_name) == False:
        return goose_group_name
    else:
        add_goose_group()
```

First if criterion checks if the input has only numbers in it, the second one checks if there are any spaces in it. When I try this code, then it checks correctly if the input falls into these criterions or not but in the return part of the code(atleast i think that's where the problem is) gives back nothing. When another function adds goose_group_name to the dictionary's key position, it prints out None.

Why does it not save the input taken from the user and put it into the key position?

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive call works like any other function call: you call `add_goose_group` to handle the case where the input was invalid, but then you don't actually do anything with the result. You reach the end of the current function call (the fact that the function you're currently *in* is *also* `add_goose_group` *does not matter here*), and implicitly return `None`, just like any other time you reach the end of a function in Python without explicitly `return`ing.

However, you should not be using recursion for this - do a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it not save the input taken from the user and put it into the key position?

Where exactly do you have an object that would store this input?

Perhaps you need something like this:

```
def add_goose_group():
    while True:
        goose_group_name = input('Insert the name of the raft ')
        goose_group_name = str(goose_group_name)
        if goose_group_name.isdigit() == False and (' ' in goose_group_name) == False:
            return goose_group_name

dct = {}
dct['user_input'] = add_goose_group()

print(dct)  # outputs {"user_input": "name of inputted raft"}
```

`add_goose_group()` will loop forever until the user enters valid input (not a digit, and no spaces), and save this input into your `dct` object.